# Does Visual Studio ignore DefineConstants in csproj?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I have a CSPROJ in which I define my own constant / compiler directive.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MY_DIRECTIVE</DefineConstants>
    <MY_DIRECTIVE>true</MY_DIRECTIVE>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then I proceed to include its use somewhere in my application, like this:

```cs
#if MY_DIRECTIVE
    System.Console.WriteLine("Yes");
#else
    System.Console.WriteLine("No");
#endif
```

Picture:

[image: Visual Studio view]

That works fine after building and running the application, but Visual Studio has both lines (`Yes` and `No`) highlighted, so if I were to do something like `<MY_DIRECTIVE>false</MY_DIRECTIVE>`, Visual Studio should "hide" and grey out and ignore the line where it says `System.Console.WriteLine("Yes");`, shouldn't it? I would expect it to, but it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not going to work because the MSBuild property (`<MY_DIRECTIVE>true</MY_DIRECTIVE>`) has nothing to do with the C# preprocessor directive (`<DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MY_DIRECTIVE</DefineConstants>`) - these are two independent concepts.

If you want to trigger the `#else` branch you have to bring these concepts together, e. g.:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <MY_DIRECTIVE>true</MY_DIRECTIVE>
    <DefineConstants Condition="'$(MY_DIRECTIVE)' == 'true'">$(DefineConstants);MY_DIRECTIVE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```